# Pentaho Report is not displayed only in lower resolution?

Tags: java, eclipse, report, pentaho, designer

We had developed an application using java-swing. In that application reports are designed using Pentaho Report Designer. In 1280x1024 Resolution Pentaho Report is displayed when running the application. In 1280x800 Resolution Pentaho Report is not displayed when running the application. Please help me to get view the Reports in lower Resolution.

Comment: Errm, check the log. Seems very very odd that resolution would cause the report not to render?  Is this exactly the same environment or is it a different PC?

Comment: On same PC, Report is not displayed.